# assigning value from a query?

Tags: java, sql

I am writing a java program which will create a database LocalStations where it needs a value maxStationid

int maxStationId;

I want to assign maxStationId with the total number of cells in the table STATION.. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are asking for

```
  st.executeQuery ("CREATE TABLE LocalStations select * from STATION");
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to write a jdbc program, which executes `select count(*) from localstations` sort of query that returns to the total count, assign the return value to ur variable .

Answer (score 2):

Can you please elaborate your question? Number of cells as in (number of columns)*(number of rows)?

If thats what you want, then you can use [java.sql.ResultSetMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)

Comment: the api link you posts is from Java 1.4.2 which is getting fairly aged at the point.  I would recommend posting a Java 6 link.